# Disallow taking pointer/reference to const to a temporary object in C++ (no C++0X)

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

I am faced with the following issue. Consider the following class:

```
//Will be similar to bost::reference_wrapper
template<class T>
class Ref {
public:
  explicit Ref(T& t) : m_ptr(&t) {}
private:
  T* m_ptr;
};
```

and this function returning a double

```
double fun() {return 1.0;}
```

If we now have

```
double x = 1.0;
const double xc = 1.0;

Ref<double> ref1(x); //OK
Ref<const double> refc1(cx); //OK
```

good so far, however:

```
//Ref<double> ref2( fun() ); //Fails as I want it to
Ref<const double> refc2( fun() ); //Works but I would like it not to
```

Is there a way to modify Ref (the way you prefer) but not the function fun, so that the last line returns a compile-time error? 
Please notice you can modify the constructor signature (as long as I am able to initialise the Ref as intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not like the syntax to use it, but make the constructor take a pointer instead of a reference. You can't take even a const pointer to a temporary.

At least, not without smuggling it through another wrapper that hopefully makes the code Obviously Wrong(TM): `template <typename T> T *reftoptr(T &t) { return &t; }`

That said, if you're using this the way `reference_wrapper` is used, your users may actually *want* to capture temporaries. As long as the Ref object is also a temporary in the same full-expression as the temporary it captures, I think it's OK. So for example,

```
some_algorithm(iterator, anotherit, static_cast<Ref<const double> >(fun()));
```

Comment: This is (to me) the closest to the stated problem (with also interesting considerations, especially the latest one), thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

No, and your code can be broken even with a normal reference. Simply document the fact, that the passed object has to be persistent.

```
double *x = new double;
Ref<double> ref(*x);
delete x;
```

Comment: +1. State clearly in the documentation how it must be used. But it is not your responsibility to account for misuses of your class.

Comment: The purpose of this restriction is to help users. Since it's pretty easy to help users in this case, I don't think it should be dismissed out of hand. Dismiss it at length, in full detail, if there's some reason why it doesn't help users after all ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pointer argument to initialize your pointer member. Do not use a (const) reference for this - use a pointer to initialize a pointer.

I have had some problems with tracking references in the past, and while it's not directly related to your question, you might find these two threads interesting:

- [Why you should never use a const& parameter to initialize a const& member variable](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/c561510cc7c53dc9)
- [Temporaries passed to constructor yield invalid member references](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_frm/thread/31ce8ccd088e33a9/84acb854471c275f?hl=enTacb854471c275f)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template. `U&` is deduced to `double&`, and that won't bind to rvalues.

```
template<class T>
class Ref {
public:
  template<typename U>
  explicit Ref(U& t, 
               typename boost::enable_if< 
                 boost::is_convertible<U, T&> 
               >::type * = 0) 
    : m_ptr(&t) {}
private:
  T* m_ptr;
};
```